# Ensure objects are closed if an exception is thrown

Tags: java

I am creating JDBC `Statement`s and `ResultSet`s.

Findbugs rightly points out that I don't `close` these if an exception is thrown.

So now I have:

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet res = null;
try {
    stmt = ...
    res = stmt.executeQuery(...);
    ...
} finally {
    try {
        if(res != null)
           res.close(); // <-- can throw SQLException
    } finally {
        if(stmt != null)
           stmt.close();
    }
}
```

(Only I have rather more result sets and prepared statements and so on open... so my nesting of `finally`s is rather deeper)

There has to a better way to ensure a large number of result sets are closed?

(Aside: in Symbian they never let destructors/close/release/remove -type methods throw any errors.  I think this a very good design decision.  That all the `close` methods in JDBC can throw `SQLException` makes things unnecessarily complicated, in my opinion.)

Comment: why you have `try-finally` in your `finally`? there should be some `catch`....right?

Comment: How about store all statements and resultsets in a list and iterate though the lists?

Comment: @Bill: In case the first `close` throws an exception.

Comment: @Bill and Bill-upvoters: `try-finally` is a legal syntax, sometimes more elegant than `try-catch`. If you need to do something with AND without exception, and you don't care to log out the Exception, `try-finally` suits better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then you should have a `catch` after `try`..in `catch` you are supposed to handle the exception caught, and in `finally`, do housekeeping, e.g. close connections...

Comment: Theoretically speaking, according to the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()), _"When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed"_. So this might save you a few `try-catch`s. But on the other hand, it is always a good habbit to free your resources "manually" :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, I know it is a legal. If you dnt wnt to do any `catch`, then your design for `try-catch` may be revisited...at least log the exception...at least.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, but your question was "why do you have that" not "is that really the right way." ;-)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It's legal, but this is a bad use of it. If an exception is thrown in the main `try`, then you try to close something and *that* throws an exception, the exception you actually care about gets lost.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you care, yes :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 7, then you can take advantage of the fact [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) extends [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

```
try (Statement sql = <WHATEVER>;
     ResultsSet res = sql.executeQuery(<WHATEVER>)) {
     // Use results
}
```

At least then you avoid the `finally` clauses.

Comment: Sadly production is stuck at 1.6 :(  But I do like this approach you've shown me and it would precisely solve these issues.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the edit. *I wonder just how rare it is for the OP to edit and improve answers to questions* :-)

Answer (score 3):

In code where I can rely on Java 7, I'd probably use the [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as [suggested by Duncan Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522640/157247).

In my older code, there are two approaches I've used:

The first is a set of helper methods on a static helper class, in this form:

```
public static final Statement quietClose(Statement s) {
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            s.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Do some useful logging here
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in your `finally` block:

```
stmt = Helper.quietClose(stmt);
```

The second approach was to use a `LinkedList`, add things to it in the order in which I opened them, and then have a helper that looped through in reverse order and basically did the above.

---

In all cases, I strive to keep the methods short enough that I don't end up with 18 different JDBC objects that I need to close. (I say I "strive"... I don't always succeed.)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than write this yourself, check out [Apache Commons DbUtils.closeQuietly()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html).

This will close combinations of `ResultSets`, `Statements` and `Connections`, handling nulls along the way. It won't handle multiple `ResultSets`, note, but is useful otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

[A blog post by David M. Lloyd](http://dmlloyd.blogspot.com/2008/07/proper-resource-management.html) from a few years ago covers this well, exploring the options and settling on a pattern of nesting a new `try`/`finally` directly above each resource that is created.  In our example, something like this:

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultsSet res = null;
try {
    stmt = ...
    try {
        res = stmt.executeQuery(...);
        ...
    } finally {
        try {
            res.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} finally {
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you go this route, it's a good idea to also follow David's advice and create a safe resource closing method that you can use throughout your project.  This method can then be called in place of the `try`/`catch` blocks within the `finally` blocks.

```
// put this anywhere you like in your common code.
public static void safeClose(Closeable c) {
    try {
        c.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Resource close failed!  There's only one thing we can do:
        // Log the exception using your favorite logging framework
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what `reporter` suggested, maintain a list of elements to close. Create a method to do the close that catches `Throwable` and returns the `Throwable`. Iterate the list collecting any `Throwables` returned and throw the first one returned.

```
private Throwable close(Closable c){
    try{ 
       c.cloase(); 
       return null;
    } catch (Throwable t){ 
       return t;
    };
}

private void workMethod(){
   try{


   }finally{
         List<Throwable> ts = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
         for(Closable c : closables){
             Throwable T = close(c);
             if (t != null)
                  ts.add(t);
         }

         if (!ts.isEmpty())
             throw ts.get(0);
   }
}
```